# I can't play transcoded streams if video codec parameter is different from "passthrough"

Tags: flash, video, wowza

I test Wowza on trial license and I have wowza transcoder turned on.

```
 (application name: test, stream name: myStream).
```

In incoming streams I can see:

```
myStream rtmp://127.0.0.1:35412 , myStream_160p local (Transcoder), myStream_360p local (Transcoder) etc.
```

To test these transcoded stream I use their player: [**`Wowza Player`**](https://www.wowza.com/resources/4.3.0/examples/VideoOnDemandStreaming/FlashRTMPPlayer/player.html) (requires Flash Plugin).

The problem is:

- I  can play transcoded streams (eg: `myStream_360p` or `myStream_160p`) only if I output these streams with video codec parameter : `Passtrough`.
- If I set this parameter to `H.264` I can play these streams in flash
  player.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You seem to get playback in both cases (whether "transcode" or "passthrough" mode). You should **add** any relevant issues, also a link to the issue in action if possible, so others can help you. I tried to throw in some thoughts anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just an **extended comment** : I'm not a Wowza expert, so I likely can't answer you.

Read the first two paragraphs of this [**Wowza Article**](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?823-How-to-create-a-passthrough-live-stream-or-transcoder). Then double-check what you are saying in your **Question** for a faster **Answer** from someone who knows...

considering..

> - I can play **transcoded** streams (eg: `myStream_360p` or `myStream_160p`)
>     only if I output these streams with video codec parameter : `Passthrough`.

Transcode means to convert to a specific video format. They [Wowza] say the following :

*"Passthrough streaming... sends the source video directly to its destination... without performing transcoding."*

Are you encoding your video in some format (via recording app, maybe?) before sending it to Wowza? If yes then [**update your Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40084507/edit) with format details of exactly what you upload to Wowza, etc.

So you can get playback *"If I set this parameter to `H.264`"* or *"only if I output these streams with video codec parameter : `Passthrough`"*, right? Flash Plugin can decode MPEG codec (h.264), VP6 codec and Sorenson codec.. so if `passthrough` works then likely you already have your video in one of those 3 formats (from recorder?) and hence just passing it to the receiver means it's ready to play on their side (without transcoding input to some Flash compatible codec). An example of a receiver is that Test player you linked.

Comment: I use flash plugin player to sent stream to wowza. Then I need to transcode (for example H.264) this stream to put some overlays on it and to get some thumbnails. And finally play (playback) this stream in player (flash plugin). If I set transcoded stream to `passtrough` ,  putting overlays and getting thumbnails from transcoded  stream doesnt work, right? . I think my problem is with my windows 2008 server (as I know, wowza transcoder need this OS to work properly?)